# Kivy KeyError when using DictProperty

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to debug one of my custom widgets and I keep getting the same error:

```
KeyError: 'page_text'
```

Here are my files for this test app I made that re-creates this bug:

Python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, DictProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('test.kv')


class MultC(Label):

    chapter = StringProperty()
    page = StringProperty()
    data = DictProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MultC, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.chapter)
        print(self.page)
        self.data = {"chapter_text": self.chapter, "page_text": self.page}
        print(self.data)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MultC()


MainApp().run()
```

My kv:

```
<MultC>:
    chapter: "test"
    page: "test2"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: root.data["chapter_text"]

        Label:
            text: root.data["page_text"]
```

I don't understand where they KeyError is coming from if I define `data` and give it a valid dictionary.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the time of parsing the .kv even the dictionary is empty for what is generating the error. One possible solution is to use the `get()` method but this will not implement binding but based on [this  discussion](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1111) the correct syntax for it to work is as follows:

```
<MultC>:
    chapter: "test"
    page: "test2"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: (root.data).get("chapter_text", "")
        Label:
            text: (root.data).get("page_text", "")
```